# How can I implement peer to peer communication with .NET 1.1?

Tags: c#, .net, p2p

The project I am working on is running on Windows NT and Windows XP machines so I can only use .NET 1.1 until we are able to upgrade operating systems. The software is distributed on a network of computers and I do not have access to the server. I am only allowed access to the client machines. Part of this software package will be running on two consoles simultaneously. One will run as a master (doing all the work) and one as a slave (backup in case master goes down). Now these two processes need to find each other on the network or determine that the other process is not running on the network to determine if it will be running as master or slave.

I have been looking into WCF and the P2P mechanisms in .NET only to realize they were implemented in .NET 3.0 and forward so I cannot use them. So I was wondering what the best way would be to perform this communication using the .NET 1.1 framework? If necessary I can marshal some native windows DLL's and create a wrapper class, but I was hoping there was something in v1.1 that I could use as pure managed code.

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure there's no p2p support in .NET 1.1.

Comment: Correct. This version of the framework does not directly support a P2P network. So my question is how can I implement a similar communication using this version of .NET? Any other managed IPC's that can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use .Net Remoting? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Looks like this will do! A little work will be needed to use the client/server architecture to my advantage in this particular situation, but it should work. Thank you!